# How to run an SP having custom-type variables on definiton via SSIS using Execute SQL Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a Stored Procedure in SQL Server starting like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReporting] 
   @DateCreated_Start datetime,
   @DateCreated_Finish datetime,
   @DeadlineDate datetime = NULL,
   @Duration [NumericTableType] READONLY,
   @ValueCheck [StringTableType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
....
END
```

As to be seen, there are two custom types a variable can have, `NumericTableType` and `StringTableType`.

What I want to do is to execute the stored procedure in SSIS using an "Execute SQL Task" in Control Flow. The execute command (SQL Statement) I use is: `exec spReporting ?,?,?,?,?` However, I don't know how I should give the parameters since the custom parameters are not defined in "Parameter Mapping" section.

I tried changing the SQL Statement like: `exec [dbo].[spReporting_AP] ?,?,null,null,null`, but didn't help. I don't want to use a script task for this, unless I have to. Any advice/help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two custom types both table types?  If so, you can use a **global** temp table that's loaded in a preceding task in the package to populate a variable of the same type, and then execute the stored procedure with this variable.  In order to have the global temp table accessible to other components in the package, the `TransactionOption` must be set to `Required` on the package, and either `Supported` or `Required` on the objects involved.  If you want to isolate this work to a particular part of the package, place all the components involved in the same Sequence Container and apply the same `TransactionOption` settings there.  You won't need to use parameters to do this, and the following example illustrates executing the stored procure after populating a variable of the same type.

```
DECLARE @TableParameter AS YourTableType

INSERT INTO @TableParameter (Column1, Column2)
SELECT Column1, Column1 FROM ##TempTable

EXEC dbo.testsp @TableParameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Some approaches to implement:

1. Initialize Custom type variables inside SQL statement. This is done by storing data for custom type variables in some SQL tables before executing SP. Then create an *Execute SQL* task which:

   - Create variables of Custom type
   - Fill in the variables with SELECT INTO statements
   - Executes the SP

Passing parameters like `DateCreated_Start` could be done with technique of String Variable [dynamic evaluation with expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37725323/1010622).

2. Script Task calling SP with all parameters etc.